# Acra crash report custom report "ReportField.STACK_TRACE "

Tags: android, acra

Gurus,
I am facing some issues where if I enable customReportContent (ReportField.STACK_TRACE) then I dont get crash report on the server.
If I remove line containing customReportContent, I see crash report on server.

```
package com.aimmds.comed;
import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.*;

import android.app.Application;

@ReportsCrashes(
        formKey = "", // This is required for backward compatibility but not used
        formUri = "*****************",
        reportType = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Type.JSON,
        httpMethod = org.acra.sender.HttpSender.Method.PUT,
        mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
        resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text,
        formUriBasicAuthLogin="azircringuitnedinglybrow",
        customReportContent = {  ReportField.STACK_TRACE },
        formUriBasicAuthPassword="************"           

    )
public class catchEm extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

Following are the permission to my app

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above code works perfectly, it is just I was not aware of the location where stack trace is seen.
Following are the steps to view stack trace
1. Login to dashboard and click of magnifier symbol as shown in the screenshot.
[image: Screenshot from dashboard]

2. Once you click details of the defects will be visible as seen in the screenshot. Again click on the magnifier symbol.
   [image]

   Now you should be able to view stack trace under summary as shown in the following screenshot.
   [image]